# How do I set additional file groups in Apostrophe 3 CMS attachment module?

Tags: apostrophe-cms, apostrophe

File groups in the Apostrophe 3 CMS attachment module specify which files can be uploaded in a file upload form. By default, Apostrophe 3 offers two file groups: `office` and `image`.

I would like to add two more file groups: `pdf` (only) and `zip` (for archives). As suggested in [Custom File Groups](https://v3.docs.apostrophecms.org/reference/field-types/attachment.html#custom-file-groups) :

> Developers can configure file type groups in addition to office and image using the fileGroups option of the @apostrophecms/attachment module.

Unfortunately there is no example on how to do that, so I referred to the Apostrophe 2 documentation [`fileGroups`](https://v2.docs.apostrophecms.org/reference/modules/apostrophe-attachments/#filegroups). This documentation mentions the default configuration:

```
[
  {
    name: 'images',
    label: 'Images',
    extensions: [ 'gif', 'jpg', 'png' ],
    extensionMaps: {
      jpeg: 'jpg'
    },
    // uploadfs should treat this as an image and create scaled versions
    image: true
  },
  {
    name: 'office',
    label: 'Office',
    extensions: [ 'txt', 'rtf', 'pdf', 'xls', 'ppt', 'doc', 'pptx', 'sldx', 'ppsx', 'potx', 'xlsx', 'xltx', 'csv', 'docx', 'dotx' ],
    extensionMaps: {},
    // uploadfs should just accept this file as-is
    image: false
  }
]
```

I extended the configuration and added it to the @apostrophecms/attachment module:

```
// modules/@apostrophecms/attachment/index.js
module.exports = {
  options: {
    '@apostrophecms/attachment': {
      options: {
        fileGroups: [
          {
            name: 'pdf',
            label: 'PDF',
            extensions: ['pdf'],
            extensionMaps: {},
            // uploadfs should just accept this file as-is
            image: false
          },
          {
            name: 'zip',
            label: 'ZIP',
            extensions: ['zip'],
            extensionMaps: {},
            // uploadfs should just accept this file as-is
            image: false
          },
          {
            name: 'image',
            label: 'Image',
            extensions: ['gif', 'jpg', 'png', 'svg', 'txt', 'rtf', 'pdf', 'xls', 'ppt', 'doc', 'pptx', 'sldx', 'ppsx', 'potx', 'xlsx', 'xltx', 'csv', 'docx', 'dotx', 'jpeg'],
            extensionMaps: {
              jpeg: 'jpg'
            },
            // uploadfs should treat this as an image and create scaled versions
            image: true
          },
          {
            name: 'office',
            label: 'Office',
            extensions: [ 'txt', 'rtf', 'pdf', 'xls', 'ppt', 'doc', 'pptx', 'sldx', 'ppsx', 'potx', 'xlsx', 'xltx', 'csv', 'docx', 'dotx' ],
            extensionMaps: {},
            // uploadfs should just accept this file as-is
            image: false
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
};
```

In a widget, I configured a field to only allow `zip` files:

```
file: {
  label: 'File',
  type: 'attachment',
  fileGroup: 'zip'
}
```

When uploading a valid "Archive.zip" file, I am presented with this error message:

**" File type was not accepted. Allowed extensions: "**

[image: Error dialogue screenshot]

How do I configure custom file groups correctly for Apostrophe 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation that we know about in a3. The way the attachment module is configured doesn't extend the fileGroups through the `modules/@apostrophe/attachment/index.js` file. Instead, you have to do it "manually" in that same file.
So in your case it would be something like:

```js
module.exports = {
  init(self) {
    const newGroups = [
      {
        name: 'pdf',
        label: 'PDF',
        extensions: ['pdf'],
        extensionMaps: {},
        // uploadfs should just accept this file as-is
        image: false
      },
      {
        name: 'zip',
        label: 'ZIP',
        extensions: ['zip'],
        extensionMaps: {},
        // uploadfs should just accept this file as-is
        image: false
      }
    ];
    self.fileGroups = [ ...self.fileGroups, ...newGroups ];
  }
};
```

You can use this same type of pattern to extend the existing groups.

```js
...
    const group = self.fileGroups.find((group) => group.name === 'office');
    group.extensions = [ ...group.extensions, 'woff2' ];
...
```

Hope this solves it for you!